# Infinity Loop and user input as the termination

Tags: python, loops, signals, copy-paste, infinity

I have my code and it does go run to infinity. What I want is that if on the unix command window if the user inputs a ctrl C, I want the program to finish the current loop it in and then come out of the loop. So I want it to break, but I want it to finish the current loop. Is using ctrl C ok? Should I look to a different input?

Answer (score 3):

To do this correctly and exactly as you want it is a bit complicated.

Basically you want to trap the Ctrl-C, setup a flag, and continue until the start of the loop (or the end) where you check that flag. This can be done using the `signal` module. Fortunately, somebody has already done that and you can use the code in the example [linked](http://stacyprowell.com/blog/2009/03/30/trapping-ctrlc-in-python/).

**Edit**: Based on your comment below, a typical usage of the class `BreakHandler` is:

```
ih = BreakHandler()
ih.enable()
for x in big_set:
    complex_operation_1()
    complex_operation_2()
    complex_operation_3()
    # Check whether there was a break.
    if ih.trapped:
        # Stop the loop.
        break
ih.disable()
# Back to usual operation
```

Comment: for x in big_set:
        complex_operation_1()
        complex_operation_2()
        complex_operation_3()
        # Check whether there was a break.
        if ih.trapped:
            # Stop the loop.
            break
    ih.disable()
    # Back to usual operation...


so for this part  the only thing I would need to do to initiate it is


if ih.trapped:
            # Stop the loop.
            break
    ih.disable()

at the end of my code then?

Comment: @Yuki: adding code to comments loses its formatting which messes with Python code, but it looks like you are largely right. You need to do `bh = BreakHandler(); bh.enable()` before the loop, of course.

Comment: I have this:  (I don't know at the moment how to turn the code here into a nicer format)
ih = BreakHandler()
        ih.enable()
        while(True):
               *Do whatever*
if ih.trapped:
                break
        ih.disable()

Comment: When I run the above code, my code only loops it once even when I didn't press ctrl C.

Comment: I implemented everything like you said but when I run it, it is as if there’s a flag implemented even before I can implement the ctrl-c. Thus my loop only goes through 1 cycle.

Where does do_cleanup come from and is it necessary?

Comment: @Yuki: I will have to go back home before I can test the code and come back to you (I am at the train at the moment). Can you please try replacing `if ih.trapped:` with `if ih._count > 0:` and tell me if it works?

Comment: @Yuki: I have tried the code and it does work as advertised using `if ih.trapped:`. You don't need `do_cleanup`. You probably also need to check the length of your `big_set`, because it obviously sets the maximum number of cycles. If you mean that you want to *repeat the loop* multiple times then you need to put it into another infinite loop and check there for a break, so the `if ih.trapped:` becomes inside the outer loop but outside the inner loop. If you still cannot get it to work I suggest that you modify your question to show us the structure of your code that you want to loop over.

Comment: Okay. So after working on it for a while, I did get it to loop more then once. But here comes the problem. Throughout my code I'm calling os.system commands for unix in loops through all my methods. If I try to do a ctrl c during these os.system inner loops it doesn't do anything. It's as if the problem split into a parent and a child and the parent died but the child kept going. It's dead.

Comment: It just hangs there. 

Here is an example:


import time
import os
from BreakHandler import BreakHandler


ib=BreakHandler()
ib.enable()
for i in range(400):
        print ib.count()
        if ib.count()==1:
                break
        for i in range(12):
                print 'WTH'
                os.system('generateASM.py -a')
        print 'yay'
        time.sleep(4)
        print 'yay'
        os.system('cd')
        time.sleep(4)
        print 'yay'
        time.sleep(4)
        os.system('cd')
        print ib.count()
        
ib.disable()

Comment: it's weird cause it seems like the program just hangs when the os.system occurs in the inner loops.

Comment: would I have to implement this class in all the python files I'm using? if so, how would I pass the count?

Comment: My first impression is that most of the time you are using `os.system` you do not need to. For example, instead of running a Python file using it you can use `execfile` or `import`. If you want to change the directory then use `os.chdir`. Then if you don't use `os.system` you would have no problem. In short, if you have a program written in multiple python files then using `os.system` is wrong. If you don't know how to do that ask another question on stackoverflow.com and I am sure you will get answers.